# Spring integration - read JDBC, send AMQP message and COMMIT

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-integration, spring-amqp

I'm trying to:

1. Read DB
2. Send AMQP message
3. Update DB

If sending of message fails, update to DB should fail also. If update to DB fails, message will be sent multiple times.

```
<int:channel id="output-channel" />
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter query="SELECT MAX(d) AS d FROM a" update="UPDATE a SET d=1 WHERE d=367"
                                  channel="output-channel" data-source="dataSource">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="50000" max-messages-per-poll="1">
        <int:transactional transaction-manager="dataSourceTransactionManager2" />
    </int:poller>
</int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>
<int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter channel="output-channel" exchange-name="nameex" amqp-template="rabbitTemplate" />
```

What I can see with this setup is that on UPDATE failure, message is not sent at all. Seems like invoking of outbound-channel-adapter is after update.

One more question - is there possibility to trigger inbound-channel-adapter programatically each time I know there is something in DB, but not to wait poller too long?

Thanks!

Comment: Please paste some exception information about the jdbc inbound adapter failure.

Comment: This query for update I created only for testing purposes and exception thrown is duplicate primary key. I would expect this to be thrown, but I would also expect message to be sent to amqp which is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update after the amqp send, make `outputChannel` a `<publish-subscribe-channel/>`.

Subscribe the amqp outbound adapter and a JDBC outbound adapter (or gateway). Set `order="1"` for amqp and `order="2"` for JDBC.

Comment: I assume in this case that I do not need transaction at all - since I expect that JDBC outbound adapter will not do UPDATE in case that AMQP adapter has not sent the message?

Comment: Correct - unless you set `ignore-failures` to `true` a failure to send to one subscriber throws an exception and remaining subscribers don't get the message.

Answer (score 0):

1)use jdbc outbound gateway i stead adapter.

```
<int-jdbc:outbound-gateway>
```

2) Loose Poller and make channels without queues.